# BQ2407 use whilst connected

Tags: integrated-circuit, battery-charging

I'm trying to work out a battery control circuit for a keyboard.

I'm planning on using the [BQ2407 IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24075.pdf?ts=1664665505680&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ24075) for managing the charging of a pair (in parallel) of 18650s.

What I can't work out is how the system will behave if I attempt to use the attached device whilst charging the batteries.

[image: Reference Application]

The typical application circuit would indicate to me that SYSTEM is powered directly from IN when IN is powered, as well as charging the batteries. I'm assuming then that if IN is disconnected, then SYSTEM is powered from the batteries through BAT and OUT.

Is this correct, or do I need to make my own circuitry to handle actually drawing current out of the batteries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "power path" charger.  It handles charging the battery while powering the system when the adapter is plugged in,and powering the system from the battery when there's no adapter through the internal "bat FET".  You don't need extra circuitry.